# Is there a better (faster) way to divide a number to digits?

Tags: java

I wrote this:

```
void blah(int num)
{
    int numOfDigits = Math.log10(num);
    int arr[] = new int[numOfDigits + 1];
    for(int i = numOfDigits; i>0; i--)
    {
        arr[i] = num%10;
        num = num/10;
    }
}
```

But I thought there must be a more elegant way of doing this. Is there?

Comment: This method doesn't work - it's buggy. You need to start from i=numOfDigits - 1;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something in j2se or Jakarta commons thats converts a number to an array of digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213375/is-there-something-in-j2se-or-jakarta-commons-thats-converts-a-number-to-an-arra)

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: It's still buggy. You need to allocate `int arr[] = new int[numOfDigits+1];`. (If `num < 10`, `numOfDigits` will be 0.)

Comment: Looks fine.  You won't get any faster unless you're talking about **coding** time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with Strings, you could do this:

```
String[] arr = Integer.toString(num).split("(?<=\\d)");
```

If you want to go from this to `int[]`:

```
int[] arrint = new int[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
     arrint[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
```

Comment: are the delimiters based on RegEx??

Comment: yes - split() uses regex to split. `(?<=\\d)` means "the previous character is a digit". I tested it and it works correctly

Comment: Is this really faster than the loop method that the question uses as an example (bugs aside)?

Comment: @YoussefG. Not faster, but "more elegant" due to less code and using API. Speed usually means ugly code

Comment: Not necessarily.  Library methods are often optimized more than you'd think.

Comment: @Bohemian, Agreed.  I ask mostly because the question had (faster) in the title and I was not sure if you were posting this due to concise code or faster code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the integer to a string using `Integer.toString` and then using `string.toCharArray()` and converting back. This may or may not be more 'elegant' depending on your worldview.

Comment: you can't cast arrays of different types :(

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Can you elaborate a bit on the `converting back` part?

Comment: Sorry, nomenclature breakdown. @noMAD, see Bohemian's answer for converting back to `int[]`, although I'm not convinced this is a better solution than your original answer. `Integer.toString` will be doing something very similar internally!

Answer (score 0):

This might be one way (i am not super proud about this :))

```
Integer number = 1234567890;               // input number
String temp = number.toString();           // convert to string
int [] output = new int[temp.length()];

for (int i=0 ; i< temp.length(); i++)     // get character at index i from string
    output[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';      // convert it to number by removing '0'
```